# 64 bit variable is stored as 32-bit

Tags: c, types, compilation

I have some issue when compiling in ARM cross compiler with a variable of type `unsigned long long`

The variable represents partition size (~256GBytes). I expect it to be stored as 64-bit, but on printing it using `%lld`, or even trying to print it as Mega bytes `(value/(1024*1024*1024))`, I always see the only 32-bit of the real value.

Does anyone know why the compiler store it as 32-bits?

## Edit:

My mistake, the value is set in C using the following calculation:

```
partition_size = st.f_bsize*st.f_frsize;
struct statvfs { unsigned long int f_bsize; unsigned long int f_frsize; ...}
```

The issue is that `f_bsize` and `f_frsize` are only 32 bits, and the compiler does not automatically cast them to 64bits! Casting solved this issue for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "I always see the only 32-bit of the real value". If it's not large enough, `printf()` won't print more digits than necessary by default.

Comment: What does `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(unsigned long long));` print?

Comment: my mistake !
the value is caluclated as:
partition_size = free_block*block_size;
free_block & block_size are only 32 bits, and the compiler does not automatically cast them to 64bits! should I delete the question or do something else ?

Comment: struct statvfs
  { unsigned long int f_bsize;
    unsigned long int f_frsize;...} this is the c struct

Comment: There are probably a lot of duplicates to this question. If you find a good one and think, this question can help someone finding that duplicate, this could be a reason to keep it (and have it marked as a dup). Otherwise, I'd delete it.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake........
the value is set in C using the following calcualtion:

partition_size = st.f_bsize*st.f_frsize;

struct statvfs 
{ unsigned long int f_bsize; unsigned long int f_frsize;...}

The issue is that f_bsize & f_frsize are only 32 bits, and the compiler does not automatically cast them to 64bits!

Casting solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The below code prints the whole 64 bits.Try printing it using `%llu`

```
  main()
    {
    unsigned long long num = 4611111275421987987;
    printf("%llu\n",num);
    }
```